# How to take organize nested list in descending order using bubble sort?

Tags: python, python-2.7, nested-lists, bubble-sort

Currently I'm working with a nested list that prints out area names and the associated number of people in a group. I've found out how to turn the numbers in the nested list into integers and keep the names as strings:

```
def Top5_bottom5():
    with open("APExam.txt", "r") as in_file:
        nested = [line.strip().split(',') for line in in_file][1:]
        nested = [line[0:1] + [int(x) for x in line[1:]] for line in nested]
        print nested
```

This prints the following list of states and stats:

```
[['Alabama', 126, 79, 17], ['Alaska', 21, 100, 10], ['Arizona', 190, 59, 16], ['Arkansas', 172, 49, 28], ['California', 4964, 76, 22] ...]
```

I'm trying to use a bubble sort function similar to this:

```
def bubble(badList):
    length = len(badList) - 1
    unsorted = True

    while unsorted:
        for element in range(0,length):
            unsorted = False
            if badList[element] > badList[element + 1]:
                hold = badList[element + 1]
                badList[element + 1] = badList[element]
                badList[element] = hold
                print badList
            else:
                unsorted = True
```

But from this code I can't quite figure out how to specify the [1]th element in each sublist that I want it to sort in descending order by. So I'm trying to get it look something more like this:

```
[['California', 4964, 76, 22], ['Arizona', 190, 59, 16], ['Arkansas', 172, 49, 28], ['Alabama', 126, 79, 17],['Alaska', 21, 100, 10]... ]
```

Basically what it boils down to is how do I sort nested lists using bubble sort on specific elements of those sublists?

Comment: I suppose I should ask why you're using bubble sort, since it's pretty hard to find a slower sort than that.

Comment: I'm just learning all the sort types now is all. Would insertion work better in this situation?

Comment: Well if you're learning sort types, bubble sort is a good place to start. Then selection sort, insertion sort, merge sort, quick sort, and on from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `if badList[element] > badList[element + 1]`, try `if badList[element][1] > badList[element + 1][1]`. You can just keep using the `[]` notation to look into arbitrary nesting depths.

Comment: Ah okay. so by using [] it will arrange it by that element in all the sublists?

Comment: @JohnathanScott yes, you'll specifically compare the `[1]` element in each sublist and sort by that. You can swap out `[1]` for any element you want to sort on it.